# Unclear usage of ように

Tags: grammar

> あの子は俺たちや秋葉が遊ぶように手を取らせる反面、いざ俺たちが遊びだすと少し離れて俺たちの様子を見守っていてくれた。

As for that kid, us and Akiha as if playing were made join hands, on the other side when we went out to play she distanced herself a little and watched over us playing.

Is ように meaning *as if playing* or does it mean *in order to play*?

How can I understand when it's used with the meaning of *similar* or with the meaning of *in order to*?

Answer (score 3):

This ように is not *as if* nor *like*, but *in order to* or *so as to*. (The fourth definition in [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226613/meaning/m0u/).)

So 遊ぶように here means *in order to play* or *so (we) can play*.

> あの子は俺たちや秋葉が遊ぶように手を取らせる反面...
>   That kid made Akiha and us take (one another's) hands so that we play (together), ...

The latter half of your translation looks good.

遊ぶように手を取らせる may grammatically mean "to make someone take hands as if he/she were playing", but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, but is it there some kind of rule or trick to understand when it means: like, as if; or when it means: in order to?

Comment: There may be rare exceptions, but ように used with verbs like させる, 言う and 命令する usually means *to* or *in order to*, I think.